# Azure Functions error - Cannot bind parameter to type String

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to save files to FTP by using an Azure Function. The json is this:

```
{
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "outputFile",
      "path": "{folder}/ps-{DateTime}.txt",
      "connection": "ftp_FTP",
      "direction": "out"
}
```

The function code is this:

```
public static void Run(string myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log, string folder, out string outputFile)
{
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PalmSenseMeasurementInput>(myEventHubMessage);

    folder = model.FtpFolderName;

    outputFile = $"{model.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss")};{model.Concentration};{model.Temperature};{model.ErrorMessage}";


    log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger Save-to-ftp function saved to FTP: {myEventHubMessage}");

}
```

The error I get is this:

> Function ($SaveToFtp) Error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error
>   indexing method 'Functions.SaveToFtp'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Cannot bind parameter 'folder' to type String. Make sure the parameter
>   Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions
>   (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the
>   registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
>   config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).

If I replace {folder} with a folder name it works:

```
"path": "psm/ps-{DateTime}.txt"
```

Why? Is it not possible to change the path from the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`folder` is an input parameter of your function, it can't affect the ouput binding.

What `{folder}` syntax means is that the runtime will try to find `folder` property in your input item, and bind to it.

So try the following instead:

```
public static void Run(PalmSenseMeasurementInput model, out string outputFile)
{
    outputFile = $"{model.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss")};{model.Concentration};{model.Temperature};{model.ErrorMessage}";
}
```

with `function.json`:

```
{
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "outputFile",
      "path": "{FtpFolderName}/ps-{DateTime}.txt",
      "connection": "ftp_FTP",
      "direction": "out"
}
```

You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings), in "Binding expressions and patterns" and "Bind to custom input properties in a binding expression" sections.

Comment: It works! :) Where did you read this stuff... I did not see it in the docs... or maybe I missed it...

Comment: @AlexAlbu Added a link to my answer. It's not very detailed, but has an example.